# Двумерный массив как аргумент

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, рекурсия

Я прохожу онлайн - курс обучения C++. Для решения одной из задач мне понадобилось сообщить двумерный массив в качестве аргумента функции. Причём функция должна быть рекурсивная, то есть она получает массив, проделывает с ним некоторую работу, и вызывает себя же, сообщая себе этот массив, что бы работать с ним дальше, с новыми переменными. Так же сложность в том, что размер массива должен инициализироваться в функции main, так как несмотря на то, что Visual Studio не принимает переменную в качестве размера массива, компилятор, который проверяет решение задачи на сайте курса, кажется, более старый/новый, и у него проблем с этим нет. Так что для тестов в visual studio я использую константы, а когда буду переносить задачу на сайт курса - просто заменю её на cin. Именно поэтому размер массива должен определяться именно в функции main. Как мне провернуть эту операцию, и нужно ли сообщить что то дополнительно?

Comment: В С++ ни двумерные (которые вообще-то в языке отсутствуют), ни одномерные массивы нельзя передать в функции. Можно передать только ссылку или указатель (на первый элемент или на весь массив). Скорее всего, как в большинстве подобных случаев, двумерный массив вам совершенно не нужен, используйте вместо него одномерный с соотв. индексированием. Далее, в С++ размер массива должен быть константной времени компиляции, так что Visual Studio тут отрабатывает правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Ну сделайте его так:

```
int ** arr = new int*[rows];
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) arr[i] = new int[cols];
```

`rows`, `cols` - число строк и столбцов, которые надо будет передавать вместе с указателем `arr`.

Это если вы не хотите использовать решение попроще - например, `vector<vector<int>>`...

Решение для массива n строк, m столбцов. Все, вы передаете только ссылку на свой вектор и все - он сам знает и число строк, и число столбцов, и обращаетесь вы как к обычному двумернгому массиву. и не надо ничего за собой тиянуть. И инициализировать легко и просто!

```
int test(vector<vector<int>>& v)
{
    cout << "Rows: " << v.size();
    cout << "Cols: " << v[0].size();

    v[2][3]++;
    v[i][j]--;
    ....

    // Нужно рекурсивно - запросто:

    test(v);

}


int n, m;
cin >> n >> m;

vector<vector<int>> v(n, vector<int>(m));

test(v);
```

и не надо никакой глупости типа

```
int test(int n, vector <vector <int>> a(n))
```

Вообще не понимаю, что за чушь вы тут написали. Вы же не пишете функцию, например,

```
int test (int n, int m(2*n))
```

Comment: Я хотел бы использовать решение попроще, но если я использую `vector<vector<int>>` , то как мне указать размер внутренних массивов?
То есть я напишу что то в стиле :
`vector <vector <int>> a(n);` , где n - размер, но как мне ограничить, да хотя бы этой же n внутренний массив?  

И второй вопрос, как мне такой массив указать в качестве аргумента? Я же не могу написать :
`int test(vector <vector <int>> a(n)) {}`
так как n определена в main...
Я пробовал сообщить и n в качестве аргумента, в стиле:
`int test(int n, vector <vector <int>> a(n)) {}`, но компилятор не даёт мне это сделать.

Comment: Для вектора можно внутри функции поставить assert на размер каждого внутреннего вектора. Дополню свой ответ.

Comment: Извините, но вы пишете чушь. Я допишу в ответ, как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно передавать ссылку на массив. Можно аналогично написать и для других размерностей.

```cpp
template<
    typename Type, /* Тип, хранимый в массиве */
    size_t M,
    size_t N
> void foo(const Type (& array)[M][N])
{
    //
    // Вот тут вот работаем с массивом 'array'
    // Если надо менять массив внутри 'foo',
    // то надо убрать 'const' выше
    //
}

// ...

int array_of_int[10][5];
char array_of_char[7][14];

foo(array_of_int);
foo(array_of_char);
```

Но тут размер должен быть известен при компиляции. Если же он не известен, то надо выделять память динамически или использовать вектор.

Что касается принятия рантаймовой переменной в качестве размера массива, то там скорее всего новый компилятор С, так как в С есть массивы на стеке переменной длины.

Что касается ограничения длины вложенных векторов внутри:

```cpp
template<typename T, size_t N>
void foo(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& arrays)
{
    assert(std::all_of(
        arrays.cbegin(),
        arrays.cend(),
        [](const auto& array) { return array.size() <= N; }
    ));

    //
    // ...
    //
}
```

Comment: даже не прочитал, но шаблон не подходит, поскольку размеры задаются в программе(не являются константными выражениями)

Comment: Так для этого там решение с вектором. N можно вынести из шаблона и просто передавать в функцию. Автор писал, что может с вектором работать.